# Lista en objeto dentro de lista de objetos no se actualiza

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
static public void agregarComida(String comida){

    listaComida.add(comida);
    hacerCuentasComida();


}

private static void hacerCuentasComida(){

    Map<String, Integer> contador = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Double> precio = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> comidas = new ArrayList<>();

    Boolean existeCliente=false;
    for (String item : listaComida) {


        String[] parts = item.split(",");

        if (!contador.containsKey(parts[0])) {

            comidas.add(parts[0]);
            contador.put(parts[0], 1);

            //Sacar precio
            precio.put(parts[0], Double.valueOf(parts[1]));

            //Llenar lista objeto

            for(Cliente clienteLoop : listaCliente){
                if (Objects.equals(clienteLoop.getNumeroCliente(), String.valueOf(tabLayout.getTabAt(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()).getText()))){
                    new Cliente(String.valueOf(tabLayout.getTabAt(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()).getText()),comidas,contador,precio);
                    existeCliente=true;
                }
                else{
                    existeCliente=false;
                }
            }

            if(!existeCliente){
                Cliente cliente =new Cliente(String.valueOf(tabLayout.getTabAt(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()).getText()),comidas,contador,precio);
                listaCliente.add(cliente);
            }

        } else {
            Integer count = contador.get(parts[0]);
            contador.put(parts[0], count + 1);
            count = contador.get(parts[0]);
            //Sacar Precio
            precio.put(parts[0], (count*Double.valueOf(parts[1])));

            //Llenar lista objeto

            for(Cliente clienteLoop : listaCliente){
                if (Objects.equals(clienteLoop.getNumeroCliente(), String.valueOf(tabLayout.getTabAt(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()).getText()))){
                    new Cliente(String.valueOf(tabLayout.getTabAt(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()).getText()),comidas,contador,precio);
                    existeCliente=true;
                }
                else{
                    existeCliente=false;
                }
            }

            if(!existeCliente){
                Cliente cliente =new Cliente(String.valueOf(tabLayout.getTabAt(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()).getText()),comidas,contador,precio);
                listaCliente.add(cliente);
            }
        }
    }
```

Les explico :

Almaceno comida que ordena un cliente, en la aplicacion puedo ir agregando mas clientes a los cuales pedirles comida , como al final debo mostrar un recibo para cada cliente, trato de guardar a cada cliente como un objeto, el cual tiene las listas de : Cosas que ordenó , la cantidad y su precio total de cada una.

Las listas funcionan de maravilla , todo se guarda perfecto en las listas, el problema viene cuando trato de mandar las listas a sus respectivos clientes, hice un algoritmo para agregar un nuevo cliente al objeto clientes, solo si el cliente no ha sido agregado antes, pero si ha sido agregado antes actualizo la informacion de las listas volviendolas a meter a su respectivo cliente dentro del objeto.

El codigo ha sido muy complicado para mi, estoy cerca de llegar a algo, pero ahora , sucede que al ver lo que hay guardado dentro de las listas que estan dentro del objeto cliente, solo esta guardado lo que se metio por primera vez . Es decir , si ya agregue 8 alimentos a las listas, el objeto sigue teniendo 1 alimento , ya no se ha ido actualizando hasta 8 .

Espero que puedan ayudarme a ver donde esta mi error.

Comment: Cuando le das al más, se llama el método agregarComida()?

Comment: @Andrespengineer Asi es.

Comment: Ok, veo algunos errores, déjame ver si puedo simular algo en mi IDE y te publico una respuesta.

Comment: @Andrespengineer y al metodo mando un String con el nombre de la comida y su precio , para trabajarlo todo en el Activity , que seria todo el codigo que se ve alli, hago split al string para dividir la comida del precio en el string.  Ya de alli todas las cuentas que hago con eso es lo que esta en el codigo.

Comment: No pude simular tu código, pero creo que eso que publique es el error, déjame saber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema se genera en el siguiente código, a tu objeto `Cliente` implementa `Getter` y `Setter`. Y en el fragmento de código que evalúa si existe el cliente:

```
    boolean existeCliente = false;
    for(Cliente clienteLoop : listaCliente){
        if (Objects.equals(clienteLoop.getNumeroCliente(), String.valueOf(tabLayout.getTabAt(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()).getText()))){
        // Si el cliente existe
        clienteLoop.setPrecio(precio);
        clienteLoop.setComidas(comidas);
        clienteLoop.setContador(contador);
        existeCliente = true;
        break;
        }
     }
     if(!existeCliente){
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente(String.valueOf(tabLayout.getTabAt(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()).getText()),comidas,contador,precio);
        listaCliente.add(cliente);
     }
```

Estás creando un nuevo objeto pero no referenciandolo para guardarlo en uno ya existente.

O simplemente:

```
for(Cliente clienteLoop : listaCliente){
    if (Objects.equals(clienteLoop.getNumeroCliente(), String.valueOf(tabLayout.getTabAt(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()).getText()))){
        clienteLoop = new Cliente(String.valueOf(tabLayout.getTabAt(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()).getText()),comidas,contador,precio);
        existeCliente=true;
        break;
      }
}

if(!existeCliente){
       Cliente cliente =new Cliente(String.valueOf(tabLayout.getTabAt(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()).getText()),comidas,contador,precio);
       listaCliente.add(cliente);
}
```

Comment: Eres un crack , merci mec, funciona, gracias por ponerte a entender el codigo .

Comment: Jajaja no hay de que men, buena suerte con tu app.